# How to understand the following code?

Tags: c, stack

```
int mill_unoptimisable1_ = 0
void *mill_unoptimisable2_ = NULL;

#define mill_go_(fn) \
do {\
    void *mill_sp;\
    mill_ctx ctx = mill_getctx_();\
    if(!mill_setjmp_(ctx)) {\
        mill_sp = mill_prologue_(MILL_HERE_);\

        // what does following 4 lines code do ? Modify %rsp ? How ?
        int mill_anchor[mill_unoptimisable1_];\
        mill_unoptimisable2_ = &mill_anchor;\
        char mill_filler[(char*)&mill_anchor - (char*)(mill_sp)];\
        mill_unoptimisable2_ = &mill_filler;\
        fn;\
        mill_epilogue_();\
    }\
} while(0)
```

How to understand the above code, now I know it aims to adjust the %rsp to point to 'mill_sp', but I really cannot understand that.

Comment: how to understand code: 0) find out what language it is 1) read comments/documentations 2) ask the person who wrote the code 3) read comments/documentations again. If 1-3 dont apply then 1a) get a coffe 2a) do something else

Comment: As a side note: Be careful with experimenting/working with this, e.g. because of answers/comments here. The comment in the middle of the multiline macro definition has broken it; note the `\` at the end of all other lines.

Comment: the comments "// what does following 4 lines code do ? ..." is added by myself to attract reader's attention. I mean those 4 lines code really works! It indeed has some meanings there. It works to change rsp to mill_sp and continue running function 'fn' within stack mill_sp.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to understand. The behaviour of the code is undefined.

`(char*)&mill_anchor - (char*)(mill_sp)` would only be valid if the pointers were from the same array. In your case they are not.

The compiler reserves the right to eat your cat.

Building macros like this even in C is absolutely reprehensible. Don't do it.

Comment: Even before, creating a VLA of length `0`, doesn't really help.

Comment: It works to change rsp to mill_sp allocated by malloc.

Answer (score 0):

the above code take advantage of runtime stack allocation to adjust rsp register to point to memory area mill_sp, so function fn will using mill_sp as the stack area.